# PHP function to update MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a PHP function to update the SQL table to keep from reusing code over and over. However, whenever I run the function, I always get 'SQL database error.' The odd part about this is I do not get any type of error whenever I use copy/paste this snippet of code and put it by itself, not as a function. What is wrong? Why is it behaving this way?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "username";
$dBPassword = "password";
$dBName = "databasename";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);


  function updateSQL ($table, $row, $value, $where, $arg) {

    $SQL = '
    UPDATE `".$table."` 
       SET `".$row."`=? 
     WHERE `".$where."`=?';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $SQL)) {return "SQL database error."; exit();}
    else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $value, $arg);
      if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {return "success";}
      else {return mysqli_error($connection);}
    }
  }
```

Comment: Incidentally, SET sets values in columns. WHERE specifies the rows.

Comment: you could use one of the many PHP frameworks that includes database implementations and avoid a lot of reinventing scaffolding like this.

Comment: @danblack where could I find something like this?

Comment: I'm not much of a php programmer however [look at this list](https://kinsta.com/blog/php-frameworks/#what-are-the-best-php-frameworks-in-2021). Most SO posts I see mention the top 4 if any.

Answer (score 1):

The `$connection` is not set in this scope (unless you're using it as a global variable, which we can't see in the code and it would be a bad practice anyway).

If the `updateSQL()` is a method of a object, you can set `$this->connection` property in the constructor (or any other suitable place) and then access it in the `updateSQL()` method.

Otherwise, pass it as an argument to the `updateSQL()` function the same way as you're passing the `$table`, `$row` and other arguments.

Comment: I did not include the $connection piece because I know that is not the problem. Like I said in the original post, the code works just fine if i remove the "function updateSQL ($table, $row, $value, $where, $arg) {}" portion. Something about this being in a function is what is throwing the error.

Comment: @John Then please update your question so that it provides a full reproduceable code.

Comment: Done! You should be able to see it now.

Comment: This answer is correct. You have a scope problem. You need to turn on error reporting as PHP would tell you this error is occurring.